# Error: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: salesforce, apex

i have written this class which i call from a trigger to prevent the user from selecting more than one opportunity product for the same opportunity, but it is giving me this error :
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
and i cant seem the find a way around it.

Here is my code:

```
public class AP03_OpportunityLineItem {
    public static void preventmultipleOpportunityLineItems(List<OpportunityLineItem> listOppLineItems){
        Set<Id>opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<OpportunityLineItem> listOfOpportunityLineItems = new List <OpportunityLineItem>();
        // get all parent IDs
        for(OpportunityLineItem oli : listOfOpportunityLineItems)
        {
            opportunityIds.add(oli.OpportunityId);
        }
        // query for related Opportunity Line Items
        Map<Id, Opportunity> mapOpportunities = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT ID, 
                                                                          (SELECT ID 
                                                                           FROM OpportunityLineItems) 
                                                                          FROM Opportunity 
                                                                          WHERE ID IN :opportunityIds]);
        for(OpportunityLineItem olitems : listOppLineItems)
        {
            if(mapOpportunities.get(olitems.OpportunityId).OpportunityLineItems.size()>0)
            {
                olitems.addError('Ce client ne peut plus loué des véhicules');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do u have a line number for the NPE?

Comment: I would say that the error can be in line 18 where you try to access some field in your map that is not available

Comment: The lines 4 and 6 also do not make any sense. You create a new List in line 4 and iterates over it in line 6. This block will never put something into opportunityIds. I guess you wanto to iterate over listOppLineItems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line 4 does not makes sense for your actual requirement, and line numbers 4 and 6 are culprits that deviated you to wrong decision consequently the wrong code. Below is the modified version of your code which will work as expected.

```
public class AP03_OpportunityLineItem {
public static void preventmultipleOpportunityLineItems(List<OpportunityLineItem> listOppLineItems){
    Set<Id>opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();
    //List<OpportunityLineItem> listOfOpportunityLineItems = new List <OpportunityLineItem>();  //NOT REQUIRED
    // get all parent IDs
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : listOppLineItems)  // YOU HAVE TO USE listOppLineItems INSTEAD OF listOfOpportunityLineItems
    {
        opportunityIds.add(oli.OpportunityId);
    }
    // query for related Opportunity Line Items
    Map<Id, Opportunity> mapOpportunities = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT ID, 
                                                                      (SELECT ID 
                                                                       FROM OpportunityLineItems) 
                                                                      FROM Opportunity 
                                                                      WHERE ID IN :opportunityIds]);
    for(OpportunityLineItem olitems : listOppLineItems)
    {
        if(mapOpportunities.get(olitems.OpportunityId).OpportunityLineItems.size()>0)
        {
            olitems.addError('Ce client ne peut plus loué des véhicules');
        }
    }
}
```

}

Regarding your `NullPointerException`, the above code (though your code is wrong, still your code also) will not get this exception, unless you call this method by passing null as argument/parameter. So, before calling this method you must verify you are not passing null as parameter, or you can just include `if` statement(checking for null) before second `for` loop in this method.